# Facebook App not found

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-apps

Mates
I'm making a facebook app.
Facebook url: apps.facebook.com/avcpacman
Server Url: https://www.conamor.org/apps/aventuracenter/pacman/public/

The back-end is based on Laravel 3.

The thing is that facebook returns 404 error, but on the server it works fine.
Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, Facebook apps POST data to the server url so you should ensure that your routes are not just GET routes.